# Load HTML data into DIV after choosing option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have code like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
    <div id="header">declaration</div>
    <div id="content">
         <div id="option">
            <span class='names'>
                <a href="#">show chapter 1.1.1 content</a>&emsp;
            </span>1.1.1 Chapter name<br />
            <span class='names'>
                <a href='#'>show chapter 1.1.1.1 content</a>&emsp;
            </span>1.1.1.1 Chapter name<br />
    </div>
            </div>
    <div id="footer">declaration</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When user click on the show link, webpage open a HTML file and to  print a content of the choosed chapter from file. (it is saved in content.html file, and content has id with name of chapter)
File example:

```
<div id="s1"><h1>1 Chapter</h1>
    <div id="s1.1"><h1>1.1 Chapter</h1>
        <div id="content1.1">
        data
        </div>
            <div id="s1.1.1"><h1>1.1.1 Chapter</h1>
                <div id="content1.1.1">
                    data
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

When user click on the "show chapter 1.1.1 content" webpage generate this code:

```
<body>
        <div id="page">
        <div id="header">declaration</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="s1.1.1"><h1>1.1.1 Chapter</h1>
                   <div id="content1.1.1">
                       data
                   </div>
               </div> 
            </div>
        </div>     
        <div id="footer">declaration</div>
</body>
```

I was trying this code but it is not working and I do not know how to open html file and parsed only some with with specific id

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">
    var ul = document.querySelector('#option');
    ul.onclick = function (e) {
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

        var p = document.querySelector('#content');
        p.innerHTML = 'Clicked on ' + target.innerHTML;

        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Is the second HTML example in a second file on the server? If so, you're going to need to employ some AJAX.

Comment: Well, for one, you shouldn't use self-closing div tags (ex: <div id="header" />).  They aren't supported in HTML 4.x.  Additionally, some of your div tags are not lining up (look at the </div> tag below your footer).

Comment: the code you have would just print 'Clicked on <span class="names" ... etc...'. To load other html file you would need ajax. If the div you have is in the same page then you could move the content or display it with css. Do you know what you want to do?

Comment: I edited my question. What about  this function http://api.jquery.com/load/ is it possible to do it with this ?      $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but the code below makes things look a little cleaner.

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">

  setTimeout(function () {

          var spanNames = document.querySelectorAll('.names'),
              content = document.querySelector('#content');

            for (var i = 0; i < spanNames.length; i++) {

              spanNames[i].onclick = function () {

              content.innerHTML = 'Clicked on ' + this.querySelector('a').innerHTML;

               return false;
              };
          };
     }, 1000);
</script>
```

If you're trying to retrieve a html file on a remote server and add its content to a DOM element then you're missing a lot of code, as in the AJAX call.

Comment: document.querySelector() will work without .body. also

Comment: OOPS. Thanks for the catch.